# Is there a personal firewall package/software with GUI available for Ubuntu desktop 20.04?

Tags: networking, 20.04, gui, desktop-environments, firewall

A tool with similar GUI to glass-wire for windows to Allow & Block network connections by particular App and IP

Good to have Features are

- GUI showing live network traffic
- GUI to see the network traffic for any particular time window selected from the past